# Preventing management commands from running more than one at a time

Tags: python, django, command

I'm designing a long running process, triggered by a Django management command, that needs to run on a fairly frequent basis.  This process is supposed to run every 5 min via a cron job, but I want to prevent it from running a second instance of the process in the rare case that the first takes longer than 5 min.

I've thought about creating a touch file that gets created when the management process starts and is removed when the process ends.  A second management command process would then check to make sure the touch file didn't exist before running.  But that seems like a problem if a process dies abruptly without properly removing the touch file.  It seems like there's got to be a better way to do that check.

Does anyone know any good tools or patterns to help solve this type of issue?

Comment: what about a ps -ef? (or [PSI](http://www.psychofx.com/psi/) )

Comment: FWIW, a simple fix for the touch file method would be to continue to touch the file in each iteration or step in the process. Then you can check the modification date of the file if it is present and disregard/delete it if it hasn't been modified within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Thank you Chris.  This seems like a nice lightweight approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this reason I prefer to have a long-running process that gets its work off of a shared queue. By long-running I mean that its lifetime is longer than a single unit of work. The process is then controlled by some daemon service such as [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) which can take over control of restarting the process when it crashes. This delegates the work appropriately to something that knows how to manage process lifecycles and frees you from having to worry about the nitty gritty of posix processes in the scope of your script.

If you have a queue, you also have the luxury of being able to spin up multiple processes that can each take jobs off of the queue and process them, but that sounds like it's out of scope of your problem.

Comment: Thank you Michael, celery might be the way to go.  I imagine I can have a job execute my management command (or whatever), and as it's completing, have it schedule another job at the nearest 5 minute mark.  I suppose that would keep it from running more than one instance at a time.

Comment: Or just have the long-running process wake itself up every 5 minutes, obviously avoiding that logic if it's already running at the 5 minute mark.