# Django Celery executing long tasks

Tags: django, redis, celery

Here is how my function looks like in views.py:

```
def generate:
 yuv_downscale.delay() // calling a function in tasks.py file
 os.system(-i file1.yuv command to generate video.mp4) //takes input file1.yuv and generates video.mp4 (consumes less time)
```

```
// function in tasks.py file
def yuv_downscale: 
 os.system( generate file file1.yuv) // generates file1.yuv consumes around 30 mins
```

The problem is I am unable to find file generated by task.py i.e file1.yuv. I am using Django, Celery , Redis server. If there is any alternate way to do this let me know.

My redis server and celery setups are fine:

Comment: Hello @Kishor Prasad! Does your question answer this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902986/django-celery-execute-only-one-instance-of-a-long-running-process

Comment: No Man, I am unable to find the file generated by task.py file. Where the file gets stored. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Unless you have a shared drive that allows you to share files from your celery server to your webservers, the file will be on your celery server.

Comment: @2ps Can you elaborate the process?

Comment: Elaborate on which process?